# ETL Hangs - SQL Server in EC2 Machine + SSIS + AWS RDS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssis, etl, rds

**Scenario:**

AWS EC2 Machine

- Source: SQL Server Databases
- Tool: SSIS

Destination: AWS RDS SQL Server (Storage 200GB)

Source databases and the ETL packages are in same EC2 Machine(r3.large).
Data is loading successfully from source databases into temp tables present in RDS but

> it hangs when loading data from RDS temp tables to RDS main table like showing 0 rows.

.

There are tranformations like look ups, derived columns etc between RDS temp table and RDS main table.

Note: Availbility zones are different for RDS(us-east-1a) and EC2(us-east-1c)

Please help me out as we need to go live in another 2 days.

Thank you. I appreciate your help in advance.